# react-native-video takes time to load live streaming

Tags: react-native

How can i reduce the loading time of live streaming ?

```
<Video source={{ uri: "************************" }}
        style={{ width: 0, height: 0 }}
        muted={true}

      />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just depends on your internet connection and the size of the media you are loading.

You could "hide" your loading time giving feedback to the user adding a custom UILoader as overlay of your video using the `onLoadStart` and `onLoad` props the react-native-video component exposes.

Comment: can you provide an example of the overlay?